# Eureka Resizable TextAreaRow in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uitextview, netflix-eureka

I'm trying to create a TextAreaRow that can be resized. I'd like to implement it in my Eureka form. I want the textView to have a small handle in the bottom-left of the view that the user can grab and resize the textView with (so they can see more text).

I cannot figure this out and neither can ChatGPT. Would someone please help me out?

```
class ResizableTextView: UIView {
    let textView = UITextView()
    private let resizeHandle = UIView()
    private var initialHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
    private var dragStartPoint: CGPoint = .zero
    private let minimumHeight: CGFloat = 100.0
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setup()
    }
    
    private func setup() {
        addSubview(textView)
        addSubview(resizeHandle)
        
        resizeHandle.backgroundColor = .red
        
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            textView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor),
            textView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor),
            textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: resizeHandle.topAnchor),
            textView.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: minimumHeight)
        ])
        
        resizeHandle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            resizeHandle.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor),
            resizeHandle.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor),
            resizeHandle.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            resizeHandle.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
        ])
        resizeHandle.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleResizeGesture(gesture:)))
        resizeHandle.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    }
    
    @objc private func handleResizeGesture(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let point = gesture.location(in: self)
        switch gesture.state {
        case .began:
            dragStartPoint = point
            initialHeight = frame.size.height
        case .changed:
            let delta = point.y - dragStartPoint.y
            let newHeight = initialHeight + delta
            if newHeight >= minimumHeight {
                frame.size.height = newHeight
                layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

public class ResizableTextAreaCell: Cell<String>, CellType, UITextViewDelegate {

    lazy var resizableTextView: ResizableTextView = {
        let view = ResizableTextView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    public override func setup() {
        super.setup()
        height = { [weak self] in
            return self?.resizableTextView.frame.height ?? UITableView.automaticDimension
        }
        resizableTextView.textView.delegate = self
        contentView.addSubview(resizableTextView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            resizableTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            resizableTextView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor),
            resizableTextView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor),
            resizableTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    public override func update() {
        super.update()
        textLabel?.text = nil
        resizableTextView.textView.text = row.value
        
        if let row = row as? ResizableTextAreaRow, resizableTextView.textView.text?.isEmpty == true {
            resizableTextView.textView.text = row.placeholder
            resizableTextView.textView.textColor = .lightGray
        } else {
            resizableTextView.textView.textColor = .black
        }
    }

    public func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if let row = row as? ResizableTextAreaRow, textView.text == row.placeholder {
            textView.text = nil
            textView.textColor = .black
        }
    }

    public func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if textView.text.isEmpty {
            if let row = row as? ResizableTextAreaRow {
                textView.text = row.placeholder
                textView.textColor = .lightGray
            }
        }
    }
    
    public func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        row.value = textView.text
    }
}

public final class ResizableTextAreaRow: Row<ResizableTextAreaCell>, RowType {
    public var placeholder: String?
    
    required public init(tag: String?) {
        super.init(tag: tag)
    }
}
```